# Rewrite when name includes Question Mark (?)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a re-write in place that is doing what I wish.
It's rewriting a URL as follows:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/?search=kuriboh
```

To the following:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/kuriboh/
```

I also have an additional rewrite to handle "/" in a name, such as:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/D/D/D%20Destiny%20King%20Zero%20Laplace/
```

My htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?card/(.*?)/?$ /card/?search=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/card(?:\.php)?/?\?search=([^\&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /card/%1? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Now I just discovered an issue that when  a ? is in the actual name of my item, only everything before the ? is taken.

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Danger!?%20Tsuchinoko?
```

Is being read as:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Danger!
```

I'm still trying to learn rewrites so I'm not sure how to accomplish this. An explanation would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: yes it seems ? is causing issue but your rules are correct, but that URL is not correct. behaviour is also correct so when you get ? in url it will be url-encoded `%3F`

Comment: so your URL can be https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Danger!%3F%20Tsuchinoko%3F